# Checking visibility of object in viewport when overflow is scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an unordered list of list items containing a linked image. My CSS is set to only show one image at a time as defined by the width and height of the containing UL. Overflow is set to scroll.

I'd like to check whether an image is visible (i.e. in viewport) (using jquery.visible plugin) and, if true, grab the image's alt attribute and append it in a P element on the page.

But I don't know if my plugin determines visibility to be true for all images being that I'm "hiding" the images using overflow in my CSS.

```
section#photos {
    background: url(../img/photo_bg.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 710px 543px;
    width: 710px;
    height: 543px;
    position: relative;
}

 section#photos ul#container {
    position: relative;
    left: 45px;
    top: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 425px;
    width: 638px;
}

<section id="photos">
<ul id="container">
        <li class="photo"> <a href="#modalPhoto" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalPhoto" data-img-caption="Parker sleeps after feeding" data-img-url="http://placehold.it/1000x1000"><img class="lazy" src="http://placehold.it/1000x1000" alt="Parker sleeps after feeding" width="638px" height="425px"></a>

            <p class="caption">Parker sleeps after feeding</p>
        </li>
        <li class="photo"> <a href="#modalPhoto" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalPhoto" data-img-caption="Stork stats" data-img-url="http://placehold.it/1000x1000"><img class="lazy" src="http://placehold.it/1000x1000" alt="Stork stats" width="638px" height="425px"></a>

            <p class="caption">Stork stats</p>
        </li>
        <li class="photo"> <a href="#modalPhoto" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalPhoto" data-img-caption="Happy family" data-img-url="http://placehold.it/1000x1000"><img class="lazy" src="http://placehold.it/1000x1000" alt="Happy family" width="638px" height="425px"></a>

            <p class="caption">Happy family</p>
        </li>
        <li class="photo"> <a href="#modalPhoto" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalPhoto" data-img-caption="Happy Mom" data-img-url="http://placehold.it/1000x1000"><img class="lazy" src="http://placehold.it/1000x1000" alt="Happy Mom" width="638px" height="425px"></a>

            <p class="caption">Happy Mom</p>
        </li>
        <li class="photo"> <a href="#modalPhoto" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalPhoto" data-img-caption="Parker naps after feeding" data-img-url="http://placehold.it/1000x1000"><img class="lazy" src="http://placehold.it/1000x1000" alt="Parker naps after feeding" width="638px" height="425px"></a>

            <p class="caption">Parker naps after feeding</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <p class="caption_text"></p>
    <ul class="social_icons">
        <li><a href="http://facebook.com"><img src="http://placehold.it/22x22" alt="" width="22px" height="22px"></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/22x22" alt="" width="22px" height="22px"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
        </section>

$('#container li').each(function () {
    if ($(this).$('img').visible(true)) {
        $('.caption_text').empty().append($(this).attr('alt'));
    }
});
```

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/patrickbeeson/VPqV3/3/

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: i dont really get it what you want to do:
even if this example would work, there would be no difference between visible and not-visible images, because caption (the p-tag) is already there and filled with text...
you want to hide caption of invisible images?

Comment: These is another p tag with the class "caption_text" that I'd like to populate with the alt attribute.

Comment: ah ok, sry, missed that. 
so you want to add the alt-text to the caption_text when the images are visible. should this also work when you are scrolling or only on page-load? if it should work on scroll, check out the answer of @Ken Wheeler

Comment: Definitely on scroll. So that the appended text is swapped out when a new image is visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check on scroll.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    $('#container li img').each(function () {
        if ($(this).visible(true)) {
            $('.caption_text').text($(this).attr('alt'));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your visible plugin isn't loading

Comment: Fixed. Had to scroll with the containing element, not window: `$('#container').on('scroll', function(){
    $('#container li img').each(function () {
        if ($(this).visible()) {
            $('.caption_text').empty().append($(this).attr('alt'));
        }
    });
});`